# regex for matching phrases even if its within a bracket

Tags: regex

I want to match 'marks' 'marks-for-days' 'reactions(98%)' 'fun-for me'

All of those even if its without the brackets like:

- marksman - no match
- marksreaction - no match

but

- marks (98%) - match
- reactions 98% - match
- fun for me - match
- there are no fun only marks - match

I tried the basic word matching but it doesnt work  `\w*(marks|reactions|fun for me)\w*`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not matching the `-` in `marks-for-days` only the spaces.

Using a character class can match either a space or hyphen `[- ]` and use word boundaries to prevent partial matches.

```
\b(?:marks|reactions|fun[- ]for[- ]me)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ddxAvh/1)

If you want to match the whole line you can add `.*` before and after the pattern:

```
.*\b(?:marks|reactions|fun[- ]for[- ]me)\b.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YlbfIK/1)